# How to configure modal widgets in ArcGIS Server JavaScript API version 4?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, widget

The ArcGIS Server JavaScript API version 4 has the concept of [widgets](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Widget.html), such as the [LayerList](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-layerlist/index.html) or [Legend](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/widgets-legend/index.html) widgets.

Is it possible to set these widgets to be modal, whereby opening any widget closes all other widgets in the same mapView?

I can't see a way to obtain a list of all widgets on a mapView, or even to close a widget once you have a handle on it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use a third party modal library and then place the widgets into those modals using the [widget.container](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-widgets-Widget.html#container) property, like this:

```
var homeBtn = new Home({
  view: view,
  container: document.querySelector('#modalContentNode')
});
```

[Here's a simple example](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/ebzava?editors=0010) of having "collapsible" widgets.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Can you add information on how to close the widgets programatically? eg, when the Home widget is opened, the Measure widget should be automatically closed